# Debug & Profile Application failure in EA for script

Tags: debugging, enterprise-architect

**Initial Info**

```
Enterprise Architect 12.0.1209 Corporate Edition 
Windows 7 64-bit machine
Using EAExample project
Trying to debug JScript-CSV in EAScriptLib in Scripting window
```

**Issue**

Okay, so when I attempt to debug a built-in script in EA, Windows tells me that `Debug & Profile Application has stopped working`. I'm accessing the script from within EA.

When attempting to run any script it just doesn't work. I press execute and it completes execution (allows me to press execute again), but nothing happens. If I debug, this happens.

Output is below:

```
Problem signature:
 Problem Event Name:      APPCRASH
 Application Name:      SSProfiler32.exe
 Application Version:      1.0.0.1
 Application Timestamp:      546ec596
 Fault Module Name:      ole32.dll
 Fault Module Version:      6.1.7601.18915
 Fault Module Timestamp:      55981b9e
 Exception Code:      c0000005
 Exception Offset:      0004226b
 OS Version:      6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
 Locale ID:      1033
 Additional Information 1:      0a9e
 Additional Information 2:      0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
 Additional Information 3:      0a9e
 Additional Information 4:      0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

**Extra Info**

That .exe is located here on my machine:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA\VEA\x86`

**Question**

Is this some kind of installation issue? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar a few times in EA v9 and more recently in EA v12 when testing and editing multiple scripts at once.  Sometimes even restarting didn't fix the issue. I ran across a post on the EA forums which recommended killing the SScripter process.